# How to declare arrays in python3

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, declare

I want to declare an array in python3. I tried but I got an error

```
Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17)
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> ip_pb=[]
>>> ip_pb[0]="0111111100000000000000011110001"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
>>>
```

After,I did this,it is working

```
>>> ip_pb=[""]
>>> ip_pb[0]="0111111100000000000000011110001"
>>> print(ip_pb)
['0111111100000000000000011110001']
```

But,I am looking for an another method. If we don't know how many values in the array, we can't declare the array in above method.

Comment: Please read a tutorial on python `list`s. You seem to be lacking a lot of critical basic info about them

Comment: `ip_pb=[]`, here list is **empty**, but you're trying to access 1st element which is out of the boundary/range of the list and hence the error. What's your question?

Comment: ip_pb.append() will insert an item at the end of your list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IndexError: list assignment index out of range - Python with an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27267344/indexerror-list-assignment-index-out-of-range-python-with-an-array)

Comment: Your way of initialization suggests that you might be coming from a php background. You might want to checkout: https://www.slideshare.net/bennuttall/python-for-php-developers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your last line (that you don't know how many elements are there in the array), you want to create an empty array and then use the `append()` function to add values into it.

The modified version of the code which you have provided in the question:

```
ip_pb = []
ip_pb.append("0111111100000000000000011110001")
print(ip_pb)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python, we usually call it `list` instead of the traditional `array`.
`list` in Python is always a dynamically lengthened, that means it doesn't have a fixed size as opposed to what called `array`.

for fixed size `array`, I believe Python itself has a standard library which you can use it with `import array` but unfortunately it has limited data types.
[array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html)

For the sake of simplicity, maybe you can just try this method:

```
def array(fill, n):
    return [fill] * n

a = array("", 10)
a[0] = "10010101"
a[9] = "10230123"
a[10] # IndexError
```

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize your array if you want to use in this way:

```
>>> ip_pb = [None] * 5
>>> ip_pb
[None, None, None, None, None]
>>> ip_pb[1] = 3
>>> ip_pb
[None, 3, None, None, None]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create empty list(array) like `x = []`
2. Add any number of elements like `x.append(25)`, `x.append(100)`

You don't need to know the number of elements beforehand, but if you want to know the count of elements in your list then use

```
print(len(x))
```

To print complete list use

```
print(x)
```

To print each element separately

```
for i in x:
    print(i)
```